# How do i check existence of multiple columns in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have tried using hasColumn() by putting an array of mandatory columns, but array as parameter threw this error:

> (1/1) ErrorException strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

That's my code:

```
if (Schema::hasColumn('table_name', ['id', 'name'])){
  //
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do over here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official Laracel doc's you aren't able to give an array as parameter. Because of that you are getting this error.

That's the syntax:

`Schema::hasColumn({TABLE NAME}, {COLUMN NAME})`

So in your case this would be:

```
if (Schema::hasColumn('table_name', 'id') && Schema::hasColumn('table_name', 'name'))
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8+ a cleaner solution would be to use this Schema function

```
@param string $table
@param array $columns
@return bool    
public static function hasColumns($table, $columns) { }
```

So the function in your question would look like this:

```
if (Schema::hasColumns('table_name', ['id', 'name'])){
  //
}
```